# How can I can use jQuery to add line numbers to a code block?

Tags: javascript, jquery, formatting

If I have the following HTML markup:

```
<div class="code">
<pre>
      int i = 1;
      int j = 2;
</pre>
</div>
```

I'd like to use jQuery to make it into something like this:

```
<table>
<tr><td>1</td><td><code>   int i = 1</code></td></tr>
<tr><td>2</td><td><code>   int j = 2</code></td></tr>
</table>
```

I am currently using SyntaxHighlighter but this seems far too complex for my simple needs.

How can I do it simply ?

Comment: What have you tried? There are many existing jQuery plugins and standalone JS projects that do syntax coloring and numbering. Have you investigated any of those?

Comment: What exactly is your question, because as asked, the answer is "yes, there is a way"?

Comment: The easy solution is to use one of the many available libraries designed to do exactly this (plus much more). For example: http://codemirror.net/

Comment: (useful tip) ask your question properly and show us your code

Comment: WTF was this question closed ?

Answer (score 4):

You might use a plugin but you may also build a simple solution very easily :

```
$('pre').html('<table>'+$.map($('pre').text().split('\n'), function(t, i){
    return '<tr><td>'+(i+1)+'</td><td><code>'+t+'</code></td></tr>';
}).join('')+'</table>');​
```

[**demonstration**](http://jsfiddle.net/WF5ED/1/)

---

Instead of wrapping each line in a `<code>` element, I would prefer using CSS :

javascript :

```
$('pre').html('<table>'+$.map($('pre').text().split('\n'), function(t, i){
    return '<tr><td>'+(i+1)+'</td><td>'+t+'</td></tr>';
}).join('')+'</table>');​
```

CSS :

```
pre table {
    font-family : courier;
    padding: 2px;
}
pre table td:first-child {
    color:#777;
    border-right: 1px solid #ccc;
}
```

[**Demonstration**](http://jsfiddle.net/McMSS/)

Comment: Nice, but you might use `jQuery.map` or mention that not every browser is capable of ES5.1 :-)

Comment: That's true. As you did it for me I'll just give [this link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) which also contains a workaround for IE8 ;)

Comment: @Bergi I added the jQuery.map version too.

Answer (score 1):

Code: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/g2XVg/). Split entire text using new line character.

```
var a = $("pre").text().split(/\n/g);
html = "<table>";
for(var k=0; k< a.length; k++){
    if($.trim(a[k]) != "" ){
  html += '<tr><td>'+ (k+1) +'</td><td><code>  ' +(a[k])+'</code></td></tr>';
    }
}
html +="</table>";
```

;